# C# - Could not find endpoint element with name 'XXXXXX' and contract

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to run a project in VS2010 that calls 2 web services locally, I have my `app.config` file set up as below and have added the 2 web services to the Services References but I am getting the following error when I try and step into code in one of the web services.

Just wondering could you help, I know that this error may have appeared here before but the solutions given don’t seem to resolve my issue.

Error message:

> Could not find endpoint element with name 'XXXXXX' and contract 'IcxnService.IIcxnService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

`App.Config` file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IIcxnService" 
                closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" 
                receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                       maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                       maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                       inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"  
                               proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                             negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                             algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICznzrzctZzzzsService" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" 
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" 
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" 
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                 <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" 
                        maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                        maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                 <reliableSession enabled="false"
                        ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                 <security mode="Message">
                     <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                                proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                     <message clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                              negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                              algorithmSuite="Default" />
                 </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_ICznzrzctZzzzsService" 
            address="http://localhost:1600/ContractNotes.svc" 
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICznzrzctZzzzsService" 
            contract="ContractNotes.ICznzrzctZzzzsService" />
        <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_IIcxnService"
            address="http://localhost:1000/IcxnService.svc" 
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IIcxnService" 
            contract="IcxnService.IIcxnService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="john@xxxxxxx.COM" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this string in your browser http://localhost:1600/ContractNotes.svc, if you don not get anything, you need to run your local web services(click on the web application, Set as StartUp Project, and debug them(click ctrl+F5)), after that Set as StartUp Project your project where you run these service refenerces and run them.

EDIT 1:
Did mark up your services with key words(ServiceContract and OperationContract) ?  like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IIcxnService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void NameMethod(some parameters);
}
```

Comment: I've added the 2 local web services to my over all project i.e. have main project and 2 web services projects that I reference from the main project. I've set the startup project as the main project and have 2 web services as dependencies and make sure that they are running but I am still getting the same endpoint error issue above. Could you give more help.

Comment: @John Did you mark up your web service with key words (ServiceContract, OperationContract) ?

Comment: Yes have this set as well re:                                                 [ServiceContract]
    public interface IIcxnService
    {
        [OperationContract]

Comment: Hi, Still haven't resolved this just wondering can anybody help on this? Tks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the configuration name you are looking for is `WSHttpBinding_IIcxnService`.
If you are not explicitly specifying an endpoint configuration name, you can check the `ConfigurationName` property on `ServiceContractAttribute` on Reference.cs file.

Comment: ConfigurationName is as below [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="IcxnService.IIcxnService")]....Does this need to change to WSHttpBinding_IIcxnService? The other web service I am using is set up similar to this

Comment: Can you try changing  <endpoint name="WSHttpBinding_IIcxnService" to <endpoint name="IcxnService.IIc‌​xnService" in your config file? Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Still haven't resolved this just wondering can anybody help on this? Tks